# Why is my site redirecting to https?

Tags: redirection, ssl

I've set up a test environment for our live drupal site so that we can test PHP/Drupal core upgrades.ee

The test sites can't redirect to HTTPS as the self-signed certs won't work on a browser, so I can't access the sites, so access must be through HTTP.

However, the issue is it's always redirecting to https when accessing the http site, even though on our test server I've removed the redirects from the vhost file (httpd.conf) and the .htaccess file.

I've also checked our drupal config and there doesn't seem to be any redirect modules or settings that would force https.

Lastly, I checked the settings.php file, nothing relevant in there either.

What else is left to check?

Comment: What’s the domain? Some browsers force https for certain TLDs (Chrome and .dev for example)

Comment: Rather not reveal it completely but xxxx.xxxx.org.uk forces https and xxxx-xxxx.xxx.co.uk doesn't.

Comment: did you try entering complete url by explicitly mentioning 'http'? eg: http://yoursite.com

Comment: yeah both with and with the http:// prefix

Comment: Clear your browser cache and check it again. Chrome like browser stored 301/302 redirect in cache So that is the only reason I can see for you are not able to visit HTTP web url.

Comment: Have you tried a different browser or cleared all browser caches? Once accessed with HTTPS at least Chrome stores that you accessed the site with HTTPS and will try to redirect you every time you revisit the site now. Chrome also does this when your domain is .dev.